# отступы внутри input в chrome

Tags: css, input, height

В Chrome у инпута появляются непонятные отступы. Всё занулил, в Firefox высота 18px как и должна быть, а вот в Хроме отображается 21px. Откуда берется лишние 3px, понять не могу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.input {
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrap">
  <input type="text" class="input" value="высота в chrome - 21px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если коротко добавьте `height` к инпуту. Тогда и в хроме и в ФФ будет одинаково. Вроде как ФФ воспринимает свойство `line-height` как `height`, а хром этого не умеет. (На счет этого утверждения могу ошибатся). Но добавление свойства `height: 18px` должно решить эту проблему.